# How can I pass an image from firebase storage to Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, facebook-graph-api, firebase-storage

Can someone help me in comprehending how can we download image from Node/Express/Cloud Functions for Firebase.

So write now I am only able to get an obj containing information about my image in firebase storage (through [`getMetadata();`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata))

```
let imageInformation = await getImage(domain, thumbID)
```

where console log of `imageInformation`  would be

```
[ { kind: 'storage#object',
    id: 'functions-firebase-43a59.appspot.com/outlook.com/assets/d547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e/1551322039811693',
    selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/functions-firebase-43a59.appspot.com/o/outlook.com%2Fassets%2Fd547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e',
    name: 'outlook.com/assets/d547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e',
    bucket: 'functions-firebase-43a59.appspot.com',
    generation: '1551322039811693',
    metageneration: '1',
    contentType: 'image/png',
    timeCreated: '2019-02-28T02:47:19.811Z',
    updated: '2019-02-28T02:47:19.811Z',
    storageClass: 'STANDARD',
    timeStorageClassUpdated: '2019-02-28T02:47:19.811Z',
    size: '162416',
    md5Hash: '0nES96sSLfY+8nvoLAdjXQ==',
    mediaLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/functions-firebase-43a59.appspot.com/o/outlook.com%2Fassets%2Fd547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e?generation=1551322039811693&alt=media',
    contentDisposition: 'inline; filename*=utf-8\'\'d547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e',
    metadata: 
     { firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: '78cc9227-a8e7-4797-9929-37983390ad86' },
    crc32c: 'c5GAZw==',
    etag: 'CO389fi03eACEAE=' },
  { kind: 'storage#object',
    id: 'functions-firebase-43a59.appspot.com/outlook.com/assets/d547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e/1551322039811693',
    selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/functions-firebase-43a59.appspot.com/o/outlook.com%2Fassets%2Fd547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e',
    name: 'outlook.com/assets/d547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e',
    bucket: 'functions-firebase-43a59.appspot.com',
    generation: '1551322039811693',
    metageneration: '1',
    contentType: 'image/png',
    timeCreated: '2019-02-28T02:47:19.811Z',
    updated: '2019-02-28T02:47:19.811Z',
    storageClass: 'STANDARD',
    timeStorageClassUpdated: '2019-02-28T02:47:19.811Z',
    size: '162416',
    md5Hash: '0nES96sSLfY+8nvoLAdjXQ==',
    mediaLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/functions-firebase-43a59.appspot.com/o/outlook.com%2Fassets%2Fd547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e?generation=1551322039811693&alt=media',
    contentDisposition: 'inline; filename*=utf-8\'\'d547b001-f5bf-b601-c8b1-4bdeb850995e',
    metadata: 
     { firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: '78cc9227-a8e7-4797-9929-37983390ad86' },
    crc32c: 'c5GAZw==',
    etag: 'CO389fi03eACEAE=' } ]
```

**What I want to achieve?**

In facebook Marketing Api, To [create an Ad with image](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative), we need to provide it a Image path

```
curl \
  -F 'filename=@<IMAGE_PATH>' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adimages
```

Can someone help me in figuring out how I can download or pass the image path to facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a HTTPS cloud function that handles the request with the provided information `domain` and `thumbID` as follows.

The HTTPS cloud function is nothing but a API endpoint that have to respond with the content data as a webserver would do. So to serve an image you need to send the raw data and set the appropriate HTTP headers (such as `Content-Type`).

If you're having frequent requests for the same image resource, then you can save yourself from too many Cloud Storage requests and also improve on response time by setting a `Cache-Control` cache header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

The Admin API for Firebase Cloud Storage is using the GCP API and you can find the documentation for how to download or query files here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#download

### Code sample

Try something like this in your cloud functions `index.ts` declaration.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

// ...
// Set up your cloud functions etc
// ...

const app = express();
export const tanam = functions.https.onRequest(app);

app.get('/thumb/:domain/:thumbID', async (request, response) => {
    const domain = request.params.domain;
    const thumbID = request.params.thumbID;
    const imageInformation = await getImage(domain, thumbID);
    const contentFile = await admin.storage().bucket().file(imageInformation.name);    
    const [fileContent] = await contentFile.download();

    response.setHeader('Content-Type', imageInformation.contentType);
    response.send(fileContent);

    return null;
});
```

Comment: It was the console log statement. I was calling meta data and hence it is obvious it won't have publicUrl. 

I got the public URL anyway. I wanted to eventually delete the question but since there is a bounty and now the answers, hence I won't be able to delete. 

I will try your answer  (later) and if it works, mark it as answered and accepted. 

Again thanks a lot for answering

Comment: So eventually what I did was, I tried a thing or two to download the image! The moment it created `whateverImage.png` the functions used to crash since probably it is a serverless architecture and you can't store anything in *functions Directory* (at-least that is my understanding). So, Any alternate which I figured out was that I was getting a `publicUrl` in console above this and then using `requestP` I sent that too facebook.

Comment: something like this `uploadPayload = {
      json: true,
      method: "POST",
      uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_${accountId}/adimages`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
      },
      formData: {
        await: "true",
        filename: {
          value: filePath.data,
          options: {
            filename: imageName
          }
        }
      }
    };
    return requestP(uploadPayload);`

Comment: You can store files to a file system in cloud functions (https://youtu.be/2mjfI0FYP7Y).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood correctly, I would comment if I could. I understood that you're trying to use Facebook's cURL api to create an ad from an image that you're downloading from Firebase's storage, correct me if I'm wrong. Have you tried passing the image's mediaLink?